# element value is returning undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a random quote machine for Free Code Camp.  I need to have one button that produces a random quote and another button that post one of the random quotes to twitter.  My random quote button seems to be working fine.  I've started work on the twitter button but have run into a road block right away.  I'm trying to store that value of the "p" element, i.e. the quote,  into a variable so I can use it to build the rest of the button.  I tried to log the value of the element just to see if it worked but it returns "undefined" whether there is a quote present or not.  I've tried to manipulate the `document.getElementById().value` method a bunch of different way but can't seem to get it to return a string.  Any insight into why its only returning undefined would be helpful.  Thank You!

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Random Quote Machine</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-header">
    <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content" id="main-content">
    <p class="text" id="text"></p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="quote-button" id="quote-button">New Quote</button>
  <button type="submit" class="twitter-button" id="twitter-button">Twitter</button>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript so far

```
const btn = document.getElementById('quote-button');
const content = document.getElementById('text');
let strValue = document.getElementById('text').value;
const twitter = document.getElementById('twitter-button');

// New Quote Button Event Listener

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en');
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    const quote = data.quoteText + data.quoteAuthor;
    getQuote(quote);

  };

  xhr.send();
});

function getQuote(newQuote) {
  content.textContent = newQuote;
}

// Twitter Button Event Listener

twitter.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(strValue);
});
```

Comment: `p` elements do NOT have a `value` property - instead of using `strValue` in twitter event, use `content.textContent` - because, once you do fix `strValue`, changing the `textContent` of that element wont magically update `strValue` variable. Note: see how you set the content using `textContent`, what makes you think you'd get the content using `value`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe because `textarea` and `input`-elements have `value`.

Comment: @some - yes they do, but there are no textarea or input in the HTML, and besides, you'de set the value using `.value` in that case, not `.textContent` - not sure I understand the point of the comment to be honest

Comment: @JaromandaX  My thought process was that content.textContent was setting a value and I figured I wanted to store an already existing value into a variable.  I thought that  using .value would return a value that I'd be able to store.

Comment: that's not how DOM elements work @jtc10 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes, I'm starting to learn that the hard way, lol.   Thank you so much for the input.

Answer (score 1):

In my code, I updated the Quote Text and The Author name using a function and used those variables when I wanted to share the tweet.

Hope that helps!

HTML:

```
<div class= "container">

<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img class="card-img" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ab008d6697a9880a9f8c364/t/5abc6961aa4a99a0ab790df2/1522693072256/background-for-quotes-5.jpg" alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h5 class="card-title">Quote of the day!</h5>
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
    <p id ="quote" class="card-text"></p>
    <p id ="author" class="card-text"></p>
    <button id = "quote_button" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" >Click me to get a quote</button>
  <a id = "tweet_btn" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
Tweet the quote </button>
</a> 
  </div>
      </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

JS :

```
var jd;
var currentQuote;
var currentAuthor;

var data = {
   method: "getQuote", 
   lang: "en" ,
   format:"jsonp",
   dataType: "jsonp"
};

var texttotweet;

$("#quote_button").on("click", function(){
      // Only change code below this line.
      getthequote(); 
      console.log(currentQuote);

      }); 

 function getthequote() {

  $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?", data, function(jd) {
  $('#quote').html('<p>'+ jd.quoteText + '</p>');
  $('#author').html('<p>-' + jd.quoteAuthor + '</p>');
   quotedata(jd.quoteText , jd.quoteAuthor );
   });
 }  



function quotedata(quote, author ) 
{
currentQuote =  quote;
currentAuthor = author;
}


 $('#tweet_btn').on("click", function(){
  $(this).attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + "The Quote:"  +  currentQuote + ". The Author :" +  currentAuthor );
    console.log("Testing out the code"); 
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

A p element doesn't have a value attribute. Try innerHTML...